# Xamarin native android DownloadManager "Download unsuccessful" error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm using  DownloadManager to download pdf,excel,word documents. Notification says "Download unsuccessful". But the file that I want to download is downloading to the correct path. Can someone help me with this.

This is my code.

```
var source = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(reportUrl);
var request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
request.AllowScanningByMediaScanner();
request.SetNotificationVisibility(DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);
request.SetDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, source.LastPathSegment);
var manager = (DownloadManager)Activity.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.DownloadService);
manager.Enqueue(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and reproduce your issue. I solve it by adding [`request.SetAllowedOverRoaming(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request#setAllowedOverRoaming(boolean)) to the code.

For example:

```
        var source = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(reportUrl);
        var request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
        request.AllowScanningByMediaScanner();           
        request.SetAllowedOverRoaming(false);
        request.SetNotificationVisibility(DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);
        request.SetDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, source.LastPathSegment);
        var manager = (DownloadManager)this.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.DownloadService);
        manager.Enqueue(request);
```

Add make sure your `reportUrl` is correct.

Comment: I need the roaming option to be "true" and anyway I added "request.SetAllowedOverRoaming(boolean)"  to be "false" to test. but still it doesn't work for os below Nougat.